# How to use Fragaria Framework in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to get Fragaria to color / Sytax highlight my Scring, but it doesnt work,

- I create a blank new Project
- Add the Fragaria Framework (it works)
- add a custom View in Interface Builder and set its Class to MGSFragariaView

I create an Outlet, call it editor.

i also add this line because i saw it in other Samples:

```
@class  MGSFragariaView;
```

Now i try to config the editor like this:

```
_editor.syntaxDefinitionName = @"Shell";

    NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"sh"];
    NSString *code = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:source encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    _editor.string = code;

    [_editor setSyntaxColoured:YES];
```

But no matter what i try, the Code does not highlight, it remains simply black with no errrors or warning, why?

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Fragaria worked  as expected, i was using a fork from Microsoft, it seems there were some issues with Dark Mode on MacOS coloring the ttext